# CPU / GPU temperature incredibly high in idle mode on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu, temperature

I have a pretty old HP Pavilion 17-e026sg notebook (AMD A10-5750 APU with AMD Radeon 8670M + Radeon HD8650G, probably around 10-12 years old). Since the beginning, the temperature has always been way too high when using Windows 10 (~70°C), so I decided to switch to elementaryOS which works absolutely fine (CPU + GPU temperatures in idle mode 40~50°):

[image: sensors output]

Now, unfortunately I needed to switch to Windows again because I have to use a lot of Microsoft Office software for my work.

**On to my problem:** On a quite fresh install, I keep getting temperatures way above a normal average (with the fan freaking out in regular intervals):

[image: HWINFO64 output]

I tried using OracleVM VirtualBox for testing, which oddly enough worked very well when it comes to temperature (~55°C), however with very poor performance and lack of certain hardware support.

**What could be the reason Windows makes the APU freak out completely while in elementaryOS the APU purrs just completely relaxed throughout the whole time of use?**

Comment: It sounds like the machine isn't adequately cooled.  Have you tried to issuing a eviction notice to the dust bunnies?

Comment: 70°C is fine. You should start worrying around 90°C.

Comment: Check if HP has drivers for your computer not available through Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound yes sir, did this just recently and multiple times before, that doesn't seem to be the issue, especially when playing games in Linux doesn't seem to make any problem at all.

Comment: It could be a power management thing.   Did you check the power saving mode on Windows?

Comment: Linux drivers probably aren't able to take advantage of your hardware like Windows does.  Often times, the Windows drivers are optimized for specific chipsets where Linux drivers are often more generic (and often open source).  The manufacturers often don't like to share their secrets and don't publish tricks to enable features of the chipset they don't want to share with competitors.  I lean toward @Ramhound assessment.  This is probably a cooling issue and Windows is able to tax those chips like Linux can't.  Frustrating for a Linux lover (me) but often true.

Comment: HP didn't provide better drivers unfortunately. Checking the power saving mode is an option, I'll check that out definitely.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas that sounds totally legit for me, however for some reason elementary handles the APU / GPU a lot better than the Windows driver does. I have no idea how to cool down the GPU the way Linux does. For me the Linux drivers are a bliss.

Comment: Not mentioned in the question nor in comment so I'm assuming you didn't install AMD drivers/software?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried both the Windows driver from 2020 as well as the AMD drivers from the Catalyst Suite and the HP homepage with no change.

Comment: The latest version from AMD should be preferred. HP, like all manufacturers, seldom releases or publishes updated drivers.

Comment: With the Catalyst software you should be able to tweak lots of settings.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the latest AMD driver gives me BSODs in regular intervals (complaining about atikmpag.sys). Basically I have no real option but to use the Windows driver.

Comment: The error is well known, you just have to google a little ;)